# Head style react-frame-component doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs, head

I've been trying to apply a style to the head element of my code with style and link as it's been in documentation (https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/2014/05/13/rendering-to-iframes-in-react/), but nothing can help me. I've been wondering is it a problem with my code or with this component. I do not really want to write all styles right in this file because it's going to be too long.

```
        <Frame     
            initialContent={'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sass/editor.css" /> </head><body><div id="sagentВody"></div></body></html>'}
            mountTarget='#sagentВody'
            id = "sagent-iframe"
            style={ styles }
        >    

        </Frame>
```

Comment: explain `head` element, are you trying to style the `<head></head>`?

Comment: yes, the <head> which goes before <body>

Comment: You can't style `<head></head>`, its job is to provide metadata for the document (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head).

Answer (score -1):

I think React Helmet can do what you are after.

[github](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

The source code is pretty simple, so I would recommend to have a look there, if you want to know how it works.